# Filtering on inner table in nested tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, schematiq

sometimes I have a nested table (table in a table cell) and would like to apply a filter on the inner table using Schematiq functions.
The general function call is clear to me, but the issue occurs when it comes to applying the right quotes to the various arguments.
I would like to filter on a specific string, but as I am already using double quotes for the outer function snippet and single quotes for the inner function snippet, I don't know what to use to quote the string I am filtering for.
I have tried several options, the last one is

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(C23,"Result","r =>tbl.Filter(r,'tier_info2','=SPOT2')")
```

Can you please help how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually very close to the right solution here, in that `tbl.CalculateColumn()` allows you to do whatever you like to the values in a column, so in this case applying a table function like `tbl.Filter()` to a column of tables is exactly the right thing to do. The difficulty is actually in getting the nested quotes right in the snippet.

Schematiq allows you to use either single or double quotes in snippets, which you're doing, however the inner snippet you're passing to `'tbl.Filter()'` needs to have quotes around `SPOT2` otherwise (in an Excel formula) `SPOT2` is treated as a named range rather than as text. To write a literal quote within a quote, you have to double it, so the following ought to work for you:

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(C23,"Result","r =>tbl.Filter(r,'tier_info2','=''SPOT2''')")
```

(note that I've added two single quotes either side of `SPOT2`)

All this nesting of quotes is a bit awkward though, so one alternative is to move the snippet to its own cell. This also probably makes your sheet a bit easier to read:

```
C24: r => tbl.Filter(r, "tier_info2", "='SPOT2'")
C25: =tbl.CalculateColumn(C23, "Result", C24)
```

By moving the snippet into its own cell, there's no need to wrap the whole thing in double quotes, so you can use double quotes around the snippet and single quotes around the text value.

Another alternative is to make the inner filter snippet into an input to the function, and use `fn.FixInput()` to provide its value to the calculation:

```
C24: (fn, tbl) => tbl.Filter(tbl, 'tier_info2', fn)
C25: '='SPOT2'
C26: =tbl.CalculateColumn(C23, "Result", fn.FixInput(C24, C25))
```

`fn.FixInput()` fixes the `fn` input to the snippet in `C24` to always be the snippet from `C25`, then `tbl.CalculateColumn()` applies the function by passing the column values as the remaining `tbl` input. By separating the two snippets, it makes it easier to see and later amend the filter logic if you need. Of course, this approach could also be combined back into one cell, and this is what I would recommend overall if you want to keep your formula in just one cell:

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(C23,"Result", fn.FixInput("(fn, tbl) => tbl.Filter(tbl, 'tier_info2', fn)", "='SPOT2'"))
```